# Collapse on bootstrap navbar is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am learning meteor with bootstrap-3 package.
I made a simple application with a navbar  with collapse class.
when i open the app in a browser and make the browser smaller (till 768px) collapse works fine, but when i open the app on a phone or tablet it never collapsed ?

the app is on : zawadi.meteor.com

this is the navbar template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- This code makes the responsive button -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cool-Zawadi</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <!-- LINK in menu !!!!
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">WELKE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            {{> i18n_buttons}}
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {{#if currentUser}}
                <a class="nav pull-right" href="  {{pathFor 'logout'}}" id="logoutLink">{{_"Logout"}}</a><br/>
                <a class="nav pull-right" href="  {{pathFor 'userProfile'}}" id="userProfile">{{_ "Welcome"}} {{currentUserEmail}} - {{partner_status}}</a>
            {{else}}
                <a class="nav pull-right" href="  {{pathFor 'login'}}" id="loginLink">{{_ "Login / Sign Up"}}</a><br/>
            {{/if}}
            {{#unless currentUser.profile}}
                <a class="nav pull-right" href="  {{pathFor 'registerPartnerStep1'}}" id="regPartnerLink">{{_"Become Partner"}}</a>
            {{/unless}}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please include the code in the `<head>` section? My guess is that you don't have the right viewport detection that would load the page in a <768px state.

Comment: thanks for your reaction after searching a bit with google on viewport i get the solution !

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />

in the header and it works

Answer (score 0):

I placed this in the header and it works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Comment: Is this the actual solution for this or a work around. As I'm getting the same issue. I've created a few test applications and it happens with all of them. I'm using twbs:bootstrap package

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this issue with Meteor and various boostrap modules, the latest one for me being huttonr:bootstrap3 3.3.6_10 on Meteor 1.2.1. Strangely the web app was rendered in Mozilla in mobile preview correctly and Chrome when reducing the window size but not in Chrome's mobile device viewer in it's inspect mode. Mobile devices did not render the page correctly at all.

adding the following as suggested to the 'head' section of the page did fix the issue for me :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

however this gave me some errors in the Chrome console all of which seemed to be relating to the 'content' section :

```
The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.
:3000/#:68 The value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
:3000/#:68 The value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
:3000/#:68 The value "0;" for key "user-scalable" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
:3000/#:68 Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
```

so I stripped this down to :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

the 'hamburger' component of 'navbar-collapse' is now functioning in my meteor project and the errors are resolved.

This meta line can also be seen in the bootstrap 'starter-template' from their 'getting started page - do a 'view code' of the first starter template to see this on or around line 6 of its raw html